# C# CDF 5/3 Wavelet - Values always 255

Tags: c#, image-processing, wavelet-transform

I am trying to implement the Cohen-Daubechies-Feauveau-Wavelet 5/3 high pass and low pass.

I am stucking at the moment. My output image is always white because all values become 255 during my calculation. It's really hard to find any examples of this kind of wavelet. Does any one see the bug in my calculation which I am not able to find.

```
static double[] lowpass = {1/8d, 2/8d, 6/8d, 2/8d, -1/8};
static double[] highpass = {1/2d, 1d, -1/2d };

    public static void lowPassFilter(Bitmap img)
    {
        int index = 0;
        double R = 0.0, G = 0.0, B = 0.0;

        Bitmap filteredImg = img;

        // Iterate over each pixel
        for (int x = 0; x < filteredImg.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < filteredImg.Height; y++)
            {

                // Apply filter in x direction
                for (int i = 0; i < lowpass.Length; i++)
                {
                    index = Math.Min(Math.Max(x - (lowpass.Length / 2) + i, 0), filteredImg.Width - 1);

                    R += img.GetPixel(index, y).R * lowpass[i];
                    G += img.GetPixel(index, y).G * lowpass[i];
                    B += img.GetPixel(index, y).B * lowpass[i];
                }

                R = Math.Min(Math.Max(R, 0), 255);
                G = Math.Min(Math.Max(G, 0), 255);
                B = Math.Min(Math.Max(B, 0), 255);

                filteredImg.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb((int)R, (int)G, (int)B));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe it's relevant that the coefficients in your lowpass filter add up to more than one. Also, you don't zeroise your R, G, B variables before the start of the filter loop.

Comment: @RogerRowland Ah yes that's it, thank you!